# How to read byte array in php

Tags: java, php

I am sending a mp3 file using the following code  to a server.In server I want a php code to receive this byte array of mp3 and convert it into file and store it there.

```
try {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/my.mp3");
    final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    final byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
    int n;
    while ((n = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    String urlString = "http://10.0.0.56/upload.php";
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlString);
    postRequest.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream ins = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    String temp_str;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((temp_str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(temp_str);
    }
    Log.e("response", sb.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception here
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
    return "exception";
}
```

Any one know how to read the mp3 file using php.

Comment: You should be able to find data in $_POST variable. If you were able to write this code in Java, opening binary file in php, writing and then saving it shouldnt be problem for you.

Comment: @Buksy i m not comfortable with php.i am a java and android guy.i searched a lot but didn't find any post which is directly reading audio file.I got post to read image but not audio file.y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your upload.php could look something like this:

```
$mp3_bin = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents( '/path/to/my/mp3', $mp3_bin );
```

Short and sweet ;)

Edit:

```
# A bit of golfing gives a one liner:
file_put_contents('/path/to/my.mp3', file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: So.. basically the file_get_contents() is reading the raw HTTP POST data and the file_put_contents() is saving the raw content to a file.

Comment: <?php
$mp3_bin = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents( '/home/m/m/my.mp3', $mp3_bin ); %>

Comment: Because you gave file_put_contents what looks like a directory.. give it a file instead ;)

Comment: see my edited comment.Now i made the file but still not working :(.plz do something.boss is dancing on my head.

Comment: The only reason this wouldn't work is file permissions.. Does your httpd user have write persmission to the directory and file where you're trying to write ? Otherwise (this usually is the case) attempt writing to /tmp/my.mp3 as /tmp is usually open for any user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26232/discussion-between-smassey-and-android-killer)